# Extra Pages Generated in the pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is a CakePHP project where I am using jspdf.jsPDF library to export an HTML table to a PDF document. The table displays monthly reports for various franchises, and I want to generate a PDF with the table's content. However, I am facing an issue where extra blank pages are generated in the PDF even if there is no content or only one page's worth of content in the table.

Include the jspdf.jsPDF library in the project using the following script tag:
`$this->Html->script('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.es.js', [ 'once' => true, 'block' => true, ]);`

```
                   function generatePdf(event) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                      //  getting all the required HTML  such as heading,  names etc 
                    var table = document.getElementById('tablename');
                    var tableHtml = table.outerHTML;
                    var contentHtml = heading + operatorDetails + stateownerDetails +           startDateDetails + endDateDetails + tableHtml ;
                   

                 console.log(contentHtml);
                   doc.html(contentHtml, {
                   callback: function(doc) {
                    // Save the PDF
                  doc.save('mypdf.pdf');
                        loadingOverlay.style.display = 'none';
                      },
                    x: 15,
                    y:20, // Adjust the y position to leave space for the additional information and the heading
                    width: 180, //target width in the PDF document
                     windowWidth: 900 //window width in CSS pixels
                  });
                     // unformatTable();
                    }
```

this is the table

```
<!-- Table to Display Monthly Reports for Franchises -->
<table id='tablename' class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- Table Header Columns -->
            <th>Franchise</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Receipt Total</th>
            <th>Advertising Cost</th>
            <th>Advertising Percentage</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        // Create arrays to store grouped reports and lower receipt reports
        $groupedReports = [];
        $lowerReceiptReports = [];

        // Group the reports by franchise name and keep track of the highest receipt total
        foreach ($monthlyReports as $monthlyReport) {
            $franchise = $monthlyReport->franchise->franchise_name;
            $receiptTotal = $monthlyReport->receipt_total;

            // Compare receipt totals to group the reports
            if (isset($groupedReports[$franchise])) {
                if ($receiptTotal > $groupedReports[$franchise]->receipt_total) {
                    $lowerReceiptReports[$franchise][] = $groupedReports[$franchise];
                    $groupedReports[$franchise] = $monthlyReport;
                } else {
                    $lowerReceiptReports[$franchise][] = $monthlyReport;
                }
            } else {
                $groupedReports[$franchise] = $monthlyReport;
            }
        }
        ?>
        <?php foreach ($groupedReports as $franchise => $monthlyReport): ?>
            <!-- Main Row for Each Franchise -->
            <tr onclick="toggleSubReports(this)" class="dropdown-row">
                <td>
                    <!-- Display Franchise Name with Different Style Based on Receipt Comparison -->
                    <div class="franchise-name">
                        <?php if (isset($lowerReceiptReports[$franchise])): ?>
                            <span style="color:#56C8F6">Franchise Name</span>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <span>Franchise Name</span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <!-- Display Month, Receipt Total, Advertising Cost, and Advertising Percentage -->
                <td>Month</td>
                <td>Receipt Total</td>
                <td>Advertising Cost</td>
                <td>Advertising Percentage</td>
            </tr>
            <?php if (isset($lowerReceiptReports[$franchise])): ?>
                <?php foreach ($lowerReceiptReports[$franchise] as $subReport): ?>
                    <!-- Sub-Row for Each Lower Receipt Report -->
                    <tr class="sub-reports-row" style="display:none;">
                        <td>Franchise Name</td>
                        <td>Month</td>
                        <td>Receipt Total</td>
                        <td>Advertising Cost</td>
                        <td>Advertising Percentage</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <!-- Display Totals/Averages for the Whole Table for five column-->
            <td class="lead text-success">Totals/Averages</td>
            
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Expected Behavior:
The PDF export should generate a single page when there is no content in the table or when there is only enough content for one page. The PDF should include the correct operator name, state owner, start date, and end date, followed by the table content.

Actual Behavior:
The PDF export generates multiple blank pages, usually seven pages, even when there is no content or only one page's worth of content in the table. Only the first page contains the correct data, while the rest are blank.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, as you're not generating the PDF with PHP, this question isn't related to PHP